# Capture users signature in an Android app

Tags: android

My requirement is to make an activity which provides user with a screen in which user can input his signs. I want these signs to be then saved as an image in database. Is there any default activity which does similar task.

Comment: Have a look at this example: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html It is a very simplified example that allows the user to paint on the screen.

Comment: Remember that capacitative touch-screens don't work with styluses, meaning that the user would have to sign with a finger... and that resistive screens don't work with fingers very well, requiring the user to sign with a stylus!

Comment: http://corner.squareup.com/2010/07/smooth-signatures.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no "default activity" designed to capture a signature, sorry.